# Angular-material set default options in md-select multiple

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-material

I tried to follow this [tutorial](https://codepen.io/badcoder28/pen/EZVKQL), But I can't make it work for `multiple md-select`. In fact I have a multiple select list of user and i want to have 2 users selected by default.

Is there any solution for achieving that?

Comment: Please, in order for us to better understand the issue, provide a plunker.

Comment: I want to be able to have multiple option selected initially for example Bob and Alice.

Comment: can you please share json object you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to track all selected users instead of just one. And remove/add them on the array on demand if needed.

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.users = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Bob' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Alice' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Steve' }
  ];

  $scope.selectedUsers = [];

  $scope.selectUser = function (id) {
    var user = $scope.users.filter(function(user) {
          return user.id == id;
      })[0];
    var idx = $scope.selectedUsers.indexOf(user);
    if (idx < 0) {
      $scope.selectedUsers.push(user);  
    } else {
      $scope.selectedUsers.splice(idx, 1);
    }
  }
 }
```

And in the view add `multiple` and switch to `selectedUsers`.

```
<md-select ng-model="selectedUsers" multiple ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}">
   <md-option ng-value="user" ng-repeat="user in users">{{ user.name }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/kuhnroyal/pen/VWeWaw

Answer (score 0):

**Controller:**

```
$scope.users = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Bob' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Alice' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Steve' }
];

$scope.selectedUser =[
    { id: 1, name: 'Bob' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Alice' }
];
```

**View:**

```
<md-select ng-model="selectedUser"  ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}" multiple>
    <md-option ng-value="user" ng-repeat="user in users">{{ user.name }}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Comment: it doesn't work!! i read on the doc that i have to use ngModelOptions because to preselect an option the function verifiy if the item preselected exists or not in the list.But when we use a model as array object then the comparaison between objects is false.

Answer (score 0):

This code defines the array of selected objects

```
$scope.selectedUsers = [];
```

You can set it by default with some of the users

```
$scope.selectedUsers =[
  { id: 1, name: 'Bob' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Alice' }
];
```

This is because `ng-model` is set with `selectedUsers`.
If you need more info about `NG-MODEL` behaviour, take a look here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

You'll also learn more about data-binding in AngularJS.

Furthermore, you will have to update your HTML to allow the `md-select` to have multiple selected value.

`<md-select ng-model="selectedUsers" multiple></md-select>`

You'll learn more about it here https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect